# In this sentence with multiple negations, should I use "is" or "isn't"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, negation

My apologies, I’m having issues with a double negative sentence. Bear in mind I don't want to change the sentence structure around, I just want to know if at the end of the sentence, I should put the word *isn’t* or *is*:

> Just because you (A) don’t feel that she’s (B)  innocent doesn’t mean that she [**is** *or* **isn't**]

I want to infer that just because person (A) doesn’t think that person (B) is innocent, she might be so.

is it *is* at the end (which doesn’t sound right) or *isn't*?

Comment: "Isn't" would be correct. "Just because you don't *feel* she's innocent doesn't mean she isn't [innocent]."

Comment: Just as the non-negated version *Just because you [do] feel she's innocent doesn't mean she is [innocent].* That's to say *[Just because] X **seems** true doesn't mean X [**is** true]* corresponds to *[Just because] NOT X **seems** true doesn't mean NOT X [**is** true]*.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you should parse it:

> You **don't** feel that she **is** innocent.

Which means:

> You **feel** that she **isn't** innocent.

But you're feeling doesn't necessarily represent the truth. Just because that's your *feeling* that doesn't mean that it's *the truth*.

---

Referring back to the interpreted version of the sentence:

> Just because you **feel** that she **isn't** innocent doesn't mean that she (*actually*) **isn't** innocent.

And changing the order back again:

> ✔ Just because you **don't** *feel* that she's **innocent** doesn't mean that she **isn't**.

Answer (score 0):

You don't feel she's innocent = you feel she isn't innocent

So

it doesn't mean that.... (what you(A) think) = she isn't